# need help creating an analyzer tool for python

Tags: python

my out put should look like this:

Welcome to the Galaxy analyzer!
How many galaxies would you like to analyze? 3
How many planets are in galaxy 1? 2
What was planet 1's income last year? 10000
What was planet 2's income last year? 34000
How many planets are in galaxy 2? 3
What was planet 1's income last year? 0
What was planet 2's income last year? 40000
What was planet 3's income last year? 22000
How many planets are in galaxy 3? 1
What was planet 1's income last year? 18000

Number of planets: 6
Planets per galaxy: 2.0

Average planetary income: 20666.67
Average galactic income: 41333.33

Income distribution: Less than $20,000: 1 galaxy(s)
At least $20,000 but less than $40,000: 0 galaxy(s)
At least $40,000 but less than $60,000: 1 galaxy(s)
At least $60,000 but less than $80,000: 1 galaxy(s)
At least $80,000: 0 galaxy(s)

Would you like to analyze another quadrant (yes/no)? yes

Would you like to analyze another quadrant (yes/no)? no

Thank you for using the Galaxy Analyzer!

Comment: Please check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I see a lot of requirements but no code. What problem are you running into? Please post code. Otherwise we can’t help you

Comment: well im suppose to create the code based on this prompt. But I don't know where to begin. I just need some assistance in getting this going and take it from there. I do not know how to create a list within a list with a user input.

Comment: i need help with nested list using input

Comment: sorry tae in kim if you don't like the way i am asking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an idea how to create a list within a list with a user input.

The idea is to first input how many lists your list will contain. Then input every element of every list, one by one, by having a "stop" marker input to know when you want to end adding elements in each sublist. I called mine "done".

This works only for `int` elements. If you input something of a different type or a different string than "done" you will get a `ValueError`. You'll have to update it for your specific needs and requirements. Good luck!

```
bigList = []
numberOfLists = int(input())
while numberOfLists != 0:
    mylist = []
    elem = input()
    while elem != "done":
        mylist.append(int(elem))
        elem = input()
    bigList.append(mylist)
    numberOfLists -= 1
    
print(bigList)
```

If you first input `3` as your `numberOfLists` within your list, then input each element, one per line, like this:

```
3
1
2
3
done
4
5
6
done
7
8
9
done
```

Should output this list:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```